# In MongoDB for C# is there a way to exclude members implicitly but still be able to get them explicitly?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, c#-5.0, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Is there a way to implicitly exclude certain fields/types in some DB model in `C#`'s `MongoDB`, while still allowing to get them explicitly? for instance, I have a `Model` with two **big** lists:

```
public class Model {
    public string SomeName;
    public List<string> ManyManyStrings; // exclude implicitly?
    public List<ComplexType> VeryBigList; // exclude implicitly?
    public int SomeNumber;
    public byte[] LittleArrayOfBytes_NotBigDeal;
}
```

And when I call `IMongoCollection<Model>.Find(SomeFilter)`, I have to explicitly exclude `ManyManyStrings` and `VeryBigList`:

```
var fastModel = modelCollection.Find(SomeFilter).Project<Model>(
    Builders<Model>.Projection
        .Exclude(m => m.ManyManyStrings)
        .Exclude(m => m.VeryBigList));
```

Yes, I can separate them to different types or different `Collection`s and associate them via `ObjectId` or so...

But the model is so "right"! they just have to be there, logically... my `Model` ***has*** `ManyManyStrings` and `VeryBigList`, it's just so much pain to start linking between `Model`s and lists of `List<string> ManyManyStrings` or `List<ComplexType> VeryBigList` in some other collections...

(btw, I don't think `[BsonIgnore]` will help here, as it prevents explicit retrieval as well. Or am I wrong? is there a way to "bypass" it?)

Comment: Is VeryBigList a growing list? And if it's the case, then I think it's time they should move to their own collection as every bson document has their own size limit. 

And BsonIgnore would essentially ignore them altogether in retrieval and insertion. I dont think there's a way that would allow you do it just one way.